# SQL self join table to find next row that matches a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a table that contains events generated by a vehicle tracker. The table is called tMain (as it is my main table), the important columns here are cVehicleId, cFixedId (the event ID) and cDateTime. The ID's are integers, cDateTime is datetime2(7).
cFixedId can be one of NEWTRIP (67), DEPART (63), STOP (64), PROCEED (65), and DELIVER (66). This is normally also the sequence in which the events will be generated.
The table contains events generated by a fleet of vehicles. The trackers in the vehicles supply the DateTime too, so the table is generally but not 100% necessarily (as the trackers might not be 100% synchronized) ordered by DateTime. The events of every single vehicle will not be contiguous (as there are many vehicles reporting in parallel), but they will be ordered by time.

Example (for 1 vehicle):

```
cId         cDateTime               cVehicleId  cFixedId
62462946    2020-06-01 15:47:35.000  27         66
62462476    2020-06-01 15:37:58.000  27         65
62461602    2020-06-01 15:14:43.000  27         64
62461422    2020-06-01 15:11:08.000  27         63
62461407    2020-06-01 15:10:47.000  27         67
```

What I want is a query that returns all DELIVER events together with the preceding DEPART (or maybe NEWTRIP) events, to see how long the trip took. This should look something like this:

```
cVehicleId  cFixedId  cDateTime                cFixedId  cDateTime
27          67        2020-06-01 15:10:47.000  66        2020-06-01 15:47:35.000
```

What I tried is finding all DEPART events and then searching forward for the next event with the same VehicleId that has EventId DELIVER. Or find all DELIVER events and searching backward for the closest DEPART event with the same VehicleId.

I have been trying a lot of queries which use self joins, also considered using LEAD or LAG functions but I don't think those will help me here. I just cannot get it to work.

What I currently have is:

```
DECLARE @DEPART int = 63;
DECLARE @DELIVER int = 66;

DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = '2020-05-01';
DECLARE @StopDate   DATE = '2020-05-02';

select * from
(select cVehicleid, cDatetime, cFixedId from tMain where cFixedId = @DEPART and cDateTime > @StartDate and cDateTime < @StopDate) as t1
inner join 
(select top(1) cVehicleId, cDatetime, cFixedId from tMain where cFixedId = @DELIVER and cDateTime > @StartDate and cDateTime < @StopDate order by cDateTime) as t2 on t2.cVehicleId = t1.cVehicleId and t2.cDateTime > t1.cDateTime
```

However, this returns **nothing**.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, and I have no clue how to continue. Maybe there are even better approaches that I'm not aware of. I did a lot of searching on the web, but didn't find anything that led me to the solution. Can anyone give me a hint?

Less important extra: it would be nice if the results were grouped by VehicledId, but that is not an absolute must.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is a query that returns all DELIVER events together with the preceding DEPART (or maybe NEWTRIP) events, to see how long the trip took.

If I understand correctly, you can use `apply`:

```
select d.*, previous.*
from tmain d outer apply
     (select top (1) e.*
      from tmain e
      where e.cVehicleId = d.cVehicleId and
            e.cFixedId in ('DEPART', 'NEWTRIP') and
            e.cDateTime < d.cDateTime
      order by e.cDateTime desc
     ) previous
where d.ceventid = 'DELIVER';
```

This uses the string versions for clarity.

Comment: Gordon, you hit the nail right on its head! Thank you so much. One small question: I tried to group the result of your solution by VehicleId but seem to do it incorrectly (I get error messages from SQL). It is not very important, but would make life easier when reading the results. Do you have a solution for that too?

Comment: Okay, forget that last question. I should not group the results by VehicleId, but order them .Thanks again.